# Unable to render multiple MultiBarCharts inside a MultiChart. Angular nvd3 chart

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I need to have two MultiBar charts simultaneously in MultiChart using [Angular nvd3](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3). MultiChart works fine for bar, line and area charts or combination of any of these 3. But when I am trying to have multiple MultiBar charts inside the chart window I am getting errors. Please have a look at the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwetMfFPYctlTWU2S0NrVGtfYTg). This is exactly what I want to build. I shall be happy if anyone can help.

Comment: Hi, Did you try MultiChart? http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/multiChart.html  .You can have two bars at a time in that

Comment: Yes, two bar charts work for the same. But I want to have two MultiBar charts